# Unity3d OverlapSphere and raycasting problem

Tags: unity

I have a grenade (rigidbody) which make a spherecast when it detonates. On each found colliders, i will make a raycast to check if it is visible to the grenade or not.

```
void Explode() {       

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);  

    foreach(Collider coll in colliders) {             

        // when the collider belongs to a player.. 
        if(coll.transform.GetComponent<Player_Controller>() != null) {                               

            RaycastHit hit;

            // ..i want to check whether its behind an obstacle or not
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, (coll.transform.position - transform.position), out hit)) { 

                coll.transform.GetComponent<Player_Controller>().TakeDamage();

            } 

        } 

    }

    Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

My problem is i will get the collider for all players, but when i do the raycast from the grenade to the found collider, i only hit the environment i play in. So basically my map. The grenade is laying on the ground so maybe there is an error in my raycast direction.

**Edit**: I solved this, the raycast was pointing not at the very bottom of the collider instead a little bit below so it was under the ground. I havent seen it unless i draw a debug ray..

Comment: If you have found an answer, write an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The raycast was pointing not at the very bottom of the collider instead a little bit below so it was under the ground. I havent seen it unless i draw a debug ray. Because my character has an empty gameobject representing its head, i point at this instead to be sure its above the ground.